# how to trim an audio file for a 15 sec frame in Ionic app

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic. I am having a requirement to trim an audio file to a 15 seconds frame. when it is uploaded from my mobile app. The trim can be started from any point but it should be of 15 seconds only.